# C# Structure that sorts key pairs and is accessible?

Tags: c#, sorting, key

Noob here. I've been scouring the internet for days, and cannot find a decent structure that auto-sorts data (like SortedSet), while still allowing that data to be accessible (like List). Here's what I have:

A list containing 100,000 nodes, added and modified regularly.

```
List<Nodes> nodes;
```

The node object, containing data I need to access/change

```
public class Node (string name, int index){ doSomething(); }
```

I don't wish to be vague, but can't sort the actual list because the index is a history of when nodes were added. Thus, I want to use a structure that auto-sorts KeyValuePair pairs(where string is the name to be sorted by, and int is the index as it is found in my list of nodes), but I must be able to access the value. Here's what I want to do:

```
// Add a node to the list, then to the structure
int index = nodes.Count;
nodes.Add(new Node("someName", index));
someStructure.Add("someName", index);

// Give name to structure, which returns int value for use in finding node
node[someStructure.findValueOf("someName"))].doSomething();
```

This would tell the node with the name "someName" to doSomething();

I am positive that I am missing something. I've tried using SortedSet, SortedList, Dictionary, etc. In each case, I can't retrieve the sorted object. What is the purpose of auto-sorting if I can't find out where they are at? Please help my poor life.

Comment: At 100k nodes, you might as well think about using a Database as storage.  That is a lot of data to just store in memory. Much less retrieve every start. And DB queries can usually do all the sorting and filtering you will ever need.

Comment: Yeah and you could use Code First Entity Framework if you don't like mucking about with T-SQL.

Comment: Nodes are actually tiny. One string, one int, and 2 Lists<int> that won't generally exceed 100 or so ints.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a `SortedDictionary`.

As per the documentation: `Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are sorted on the key.` Although, as some comments say, those 100k objects would be better kept in a database...

Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Certainly close, but I cannot access the data in the SortedDictionary (I think). I'm looking for a structure with some sort of getValue method, so that I can use a binary search to find the key and return the value. I'm sure there's a way to do this with most structures but I'm blind to it.

Comment: If you need to use the data as a key, then keep two SortedDictionaries ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SortedList` and LINQ:

```
SortedList<int,string> list = new SortedList<int, string>();

list.Add(1, "name1");
list.Add(2, "name2");;

var c = list.Select(x => x.Value == "name2").FirstOrDefault();
```

However I agree with a [Christopher's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3346583/christopher) comment about using db.